# How to prove the inequality of undefined function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inequalities

For example, how to prove the following inequality?

```
Assuming[a < b && Element[{a, b}, Reals], Refine[Abs[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]] <= Integrate[Abs[f[x]], {x, a, b}]]]
```

Comment: I think that is a matter of the future. (It's unclear to me  whether the game is worth the candle.) At the present, making use of Mathematica, one can prove the inequality for small finite symbolic sums over reals, e.g. `n = 12; FindInstance[
 RealAbs[Sum[f[k], {k, 1, n}]] > Sum[RealAbs[f[k]], {k, 1, n}], 
 Table[f[k], {k, 1, n}], Reals]` performs `{}`.

Comment: Thanks! @user64494